# I wonder why the author used calligraphic font for $Y$ in "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 11 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in this book.

[image]

I wonder why the author used calligraphic font for $Y$.
Is this an erratum?
Or this is not calligraphic font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That upper-case $Y$ is not from a calligraphic font. It comes from URW Palladio (a legal clone of Palatino), which is the font used throughout the book for upper- and lower-case Latin letters in math mode. Thus the $Y$ comes from the same font as the $X$, $E$, and $F$ in that exercise, as is logical. The $\mathcal{T}$ and the $\mathcal{S}$ in that exercise do come from a calligraphic font because they are collections of sets.

Comment: Professor Sheldon Axler, Thank you very much for your answer and your books.